# ignore object name recebeuuser

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want it to ignore the element with the initial "recebeu" and only send what starts with "user", how can I do that?...

```
const array = [
  {
    member: "Joao",
    user: {

      user: "id1",
      user2: "id2",
      user3: "null",
      recebeuuser: "null"
    },
  },
  {
    member: "Pedro",
    user: {
      user: "id1",
      user2: "id2",
      user3: "null",
      recebeuuser: "name"
    },
  },
];

const filteredUsers = (user) => Object.values(user).filter(u =>
  u !== 'null' && typeof u === 'string'
)

const mentionUser = (user) => `<@${user}>`

const stringify = (m) => `${m.member} - ${filteredUsers(m.user).map(mentionUser).join(', ')}`
console.log(array.map(stringify).join('\n'))
```

```
Joao - <@id1>, <@id2>
Pedro - <@id1>, <@id2>, <@name>
```

Comment: What does "ignore" mean?

Comment: That it does not send anything from the object recebeuser, only from the user, user2, user3 @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: What did you think up as possible solution(s) and where in the code that you're showing are you already trying to do something based on that? Because setting key values to `undefined` based on the key's name isn't particularly hard, but I don't see any code that even tries to do that.

Comment: You can just filter the entries instead of just the values. `Object.entries(user).filter(([k, u]) => k.startsWith('user') && u !== 'null' && typeof u === 'string')`

Comment: the return is being the last one, i just wish it would return
Joao - <@id1>, <@id2>
Pedro - <@id1>, <@id2>

Comment: @pilchard return Joao - <@user,id1>, <@user2,id2>
Pedro - <@user,id1>, <@user2,id2>
and without sending user. and only id1?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to handle the `[key, value]` tuples, but I figured you could do some of the work.

Comment: @pilchard I don't know...

Comment: What do you mean "I don't know"? You have [MDN at your disposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), not to mention literally the entire rest of the search-engine-indexed internet: _make use of it_.

Comment: @pilchard well, I took a look and couldn't see how I can send only the value and not send the name of the object... if you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you're using a lot of shortcuts without fully understanding the shape of what you're passing around. I would recommend simplifying the code and avoiding shorthand notation.

Here is a refactored version of what you are doing using a simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop iterating over the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the `user` property of each passed object. If the key and value pass all the conditions a formatted string is pushed to the `users` array. Finally it returns the fully formatted string.

```js
function stringifyMember(memberObject) {
  const { member, user } = memberObject;

  const users = [];
  for (const [k, u] of Object.entries(user)) {
    if (k.startsWith('user') && u !== 'null' && typeof u === 'string') {
      users.push(`<@${u}>`)
    }
  }

  return `${member} - ${users.join(', ')}`
}

const array = [{ member: "Joao", user: { user: "id1", user2: "id2", user3: "null", recebeuuser: "null" }, }, { member: "Pedro", user: { user: "id1", user2: "id2", user3: "null", recebeuuser: "name" }, },];

console.log(array.map(m => stringifyMember(m)).join('\n'))
```

also see:

- [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)